# Windows and Mac project under Git

Tags: windows, macos, git

I'm trying to set up a software project under Git. The project will be compiled both on Mac and Windows computers. The vast majority of the files are the same in both the Mac and Windows versions, but there are a few cases where I want the following:

File xxx exists in a Mac and a Windows version. I want both versions stored in the Git repository, but on the Mac computer I want to access and modify only the Mac version, and on the Windows computer I want to access and modify only the Windows version.

File yyy exists in the Mac version but is absent in the Windows version. When I use a Mac computer to pull the project from the Git server, I want the file yyy included; but when I use a Windows computer to pull the project from the Git server, I don't want the yyy file.

What is the best approach to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the composition and size of the files, you can either:

1. organize them by environment and update your compilation procedure to account for multiple environments. This is the common approach and I never had a problem with this approach for the stacks I have worked on (java, rails)
2. relocate them into separate repositories ([submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules))

Comment: Thank you, prusswan, I think your #1 is what I'll try first.

Answer (score 0):

Scripting may be your best choice.

Answer (score 0):

Two branches (mergeable), two (different) remotes for clients?